# Difference between data mining and data minimization

Tags: iot

What is the difference between data mining and data minimization.
Especially in the context of Internet of things.Most of the information gathered by me was about the data minimizing role in the internet of things,but no one has discussed their co relation.

Comment: This is an opinion based question. Is there a specific task that you need assistance with ?

Comment: The difference is that they are not the same thing, even slightly.